# How to avoid '@' sign expansion in `vega@3`

Tags: javascript, requirejs, cdn, vega, jsdelivr

In an HTML script, a call to fetch a package ending in `vega@n` where `n` is a version number, is being incorrectly expanded and causing a 404 error. I'm trying to find out why, and to prevent this.

Apologies in advance for the long-winded explanation, but I'm not sure where the problem lies so I'm trying to be as specific as possible.

I'm following the user guide to try and load a vis into a [jupyter notebook](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/). This executes the script in-browser, I believe, but for some reason has support for `requireJS`, which means that global modules aren't correctly loaded when using [the import method](https://vega.github.io/vega/usage/#import), which basically uses html's `<script>` tags to load the module.

This can be worked around by calling `define`, as described in a similar problem with D3, here: https://github.com/mpld3/mpld3/issues/33#issuecomment-32101013.

I've written this gist to show a working example:

https://gist.github.com/lJoublanc/439e2f687b7aedd6fbdea5adab5cee0f

However, for some reason (either `requireJS` or something else - my JS knowledge is limited), expands URLs of the form `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega@3` into something like `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega@3.js?v=20180324103700` which results in a 404 error.

Using the github URL (i.e. without the `@3`) works fine though.

Any idea if this is `requireJS` doing this, or the CDN? How would I work around it?

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your original question but you can use https://github.com/vega/ipyvega to use Vega in Jupyter notebooks.

Comment: @dominik I'm afraid I'm using a **scala** language kernel, so this won't work. However I'll have a look at how it's implemented in ipyvega to see if I can replicate that.

Comment: Hmm, that expansion seems odd. Can you use https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega@3/build/vega.min.js instead?